# When to use Phonegaps media.release()

Tags: cordova, media, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to understand media.release and have a specific scenario which I'm unsure if it would be required...

I'm using phonegap android to record audio. When the record button is pushed and a new Media() object is created should I first be checking if a Media object exists and release() it if it does exist?

something like:

```
var mediaRec = null;

function startRecording() {

    //release media if present
    if(!mediaRec === null){
      mediaRec.release();
    }

    // Create your Media object
    mediaRec = new Media(src,...);

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();
}
```

... the user has an option of re-recording and playing back the recording and I'm wondering if this would use the same instance or create multiple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you need to use release when you need to play a bunch of different sounds. There is a finite amount of open core instance on Android. I think 7 on my phone so if I try to create the 8th Media object it fails so I need to release one first. You are probably best to release the Media object if you won't need it anymore in your app.